# Predicate for relationship in realm, check to see if list is empty

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

```
class User: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let tasks = List<Task>()
}

let realm = try! Realm()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tasks != nil")
users = realm.objects(User).filter(predicate)
```

I need to fetch all the users saved into the database which have tasks saved to them. Like the predicate suggests, every user MUST have tasks, if the user does not does not don't fetch them. Obviously the predicate I provided does not work and always crashes with the message 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations' . Anyway, how could I make this work?

Answer (score 6):

Found it in the docs [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate):

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tasks.@count > 0")
```